# How do you convert older Google Docs to newest Document editor?

Tags: google-drive

When you create new Text documents in Google Docs, you get the nice new Document Editor with chat and real time collaboration.

How do you update older docs (from before the new editor was released) to take advantage of the new features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be an upgrade tool available within Google Docs yet. The only way I can think of doing it is to create a new empty document and copy and paste from the old document to the new document.

Comment: Doesn't pick up the comments

Answer (score 3):

You can download the old one and then upload to a new document..

From inside the old document

**File** -> **Download As** -> **Word**

Then

**Upload** -> (*select file*) and check the

> Convert documents, presentations, and
>   spreadsheets to the corresponding
>   Google Docs formats